# android: couldn't find import for class error in aidl files com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.NetworkInfo

Tags: android, linker, aidl, build-error

I am trying to re-use `PhoneUtils.java` (`~/android_src/packages/apps/
Phone/src/com/android/phone/`) within my app with some customizations.

I have added `INetworkQueryServiceCallback.aidl` and
`INetworkQueryService.aidl` into my app folder (`~/android_src/packages/
apps/USSDActivity/src/com/myapp/ussdactivitytest`) however when i am
building alongside android source I am getting the following error:

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Aidl: com.myapp.ussdactivity <= packages/apps/USSDActivity/src/com/myapp/ussdactivitytest/INetworkQueryService.aidl
Aidl: com.myapp.ussdactivity <= packages/apps/USSDActivity/src/com/myapp/ussdactivitytest/INetworkQueryServiceCallback.aidl
packages/apps/USSDActivity/src/com/myapp/ussdactivitytest/INetworkQueryServiceCallback.aidl:19: couldn't find import for class com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.NetworkInfo
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/com.myapp.ussdactivity_intermediates/src/src/com/myapp/ussdactivitytest/INetworkQueryServiceCallback.java] Error 1
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
        src/com/myapp/ussdactivitytest/EventLogTags.logtags \
        src/com/myapp/ussdactivitytest/INetworkQueryService.aidl \
        src/com/myapp/ussdactivitytest/INetworkQueryServiceCallback.aidl

LOCAL_MODULE := com.myapp.ussdactivity
include $(BUILD_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := com.android.phone.common
LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := core framework
LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES += $(FRAMEWORKS_BASE_JAVA_SRC_DIRS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
        src/com/myapp/ussdactivitytest/EventLogTags.logtags \
        src/com/myapp/ussdactivitytest/INetworkQueryService.aidl \
        src/com/myapp/ussdactivitytest/INetworkQueryServiceCallback.aidl
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := USSDActivity
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

Comment: I think you should see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10738095/1432127)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, add the following lines framework.aidl. (Platforms \ android-9 \ framework.aidl)

`parcelable com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.NetworkInfo;`