# android aidl import

Tags: android, import, aidl

I'm trying to import android.content.Context to AIDL file but eclipse doesn't recognize it..

here's my code:

```
package nsip.net;

import android.content.Context; // error couldn't find import for class ...

interface IMyContactsService{

void printToast(Context context, String text);

}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 8):

Using `android.content.Context` isn't going to work since it doesn't implement `android.os.Parcelable`.

However - ff you have a class (`MyExampleParcelable` for instance) that you want to transfer in an AIDL interface (& that actually implements `Parcelable`) you create an `.aidl` file, `MyExampleParcelable.aidl` in which you write:

```
package the.package.where.the.class.is;

parcelable MyExampleParcelable;
```

---

Now, unless you desperately want to talk across processes you should consider local services.
**Edit**(slightly more helpful):

Is this a *local service* (i.e. it will only be used inside your own application & process)? In these cases it's usually just better to implement a binder and return that directly.

```
public class SomeService extends Service {
    ....
    ....
    public class SomeServiceBinder extends Binder {
        public SomeService getSomeService() {
            return SomeService.this;
        }
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new SomeServiceBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public void printToast(Context context, String text) {
        // Why are you even passing Context here? A Service can create Toasts by it self.
        ....
        ....
    }
    // And all other methods you want the caller to be able to invoke on
    // your service.
}
```

Basically, when the `Activity` has bound to your service it will simply cast the resulting `IBinder` to `SomeService.SomeServiceBinder`, call `SomeService.SomeServiceBinder#getSomeService()` - and ***bang***, access to the running `Service` instance + you can call stuff in its API.

Comment: I named my aidl file that declared an object Parcelable something other than the same as the class name, because Android Studio **complained** that the aidl file had the same name as an existing class in the creation prompt (New -> AIDL File). I spent hours with this same error!

The file that declares your object Parcelable needs to have the exact same name as the object.

Comment: @Waffles For my test ,this may be a bug for Android studio .I create a different name AIDL file ,but still error . So ,finally ,I use Refactor => Rename to change the name to the same with our Parcelable java file. **And ,it works!**  Note that: we need to import the AIDL file when we want to use the Parcelable file in our project

Comment: Another tip I found is that: Why the class  **android.graphics.Point**  also just implement Parcelable ,but if we use it in AIDL . we don't need to import it ?

So,I search the Android source file with file name **"Point"**  ,and get a file **Point.aidl** . That's the reason . Google help us to write the Point's AIDL file and when compile the Point.java into our project , Android Studio auto helps us to import it

Comment: When I create an AIDL file for the parcelable class, I get another error: `interface Event should be declared in a file called com/zkteco/android/core/Event.aidl`. I also had it compile before without the need to create a separate AIDL file for the parcelable class. You just need to import it and declare it parcelable on the AIDL interface.