# connection two app via iadl and importing doesnt work

Tags: java, android

i want to connect two application via IADL in android abd i have a problem right now. i create first app and add iadl file to it's /src folder and there is no any error. but when i want to create second app and following to google documentation i have to import first app iadl in my code by this:

```
import com.example.app.Myiadl;
```

but when i wirute this line it doesnt resolve and i have a red line under com.example... what is this? how i can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Please write more code, how you import aidl (not import statement). Red line means compiler don't know this package. I think you misunderstand how it works, please read this tutorials:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html
- [AIDL interface between two applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656689/aidl-interface-between-two-applications)
- [android aidl import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737931/android-aidl-import)